# Creating an admin page that updates table fields

Tags: php, pdo, admin, updating

What I am trying to create is an admin page to edit a table in a database. This admin page allows me to edit items on a separate web page called index.php. I have setup the structure for the admin page but am lost as to where to begin with implementing updating to my table. I really need some direction on how to accomplish this. The admin page as well as the index.php is currently working correctly as far as displaying the data from tblContent. There is only one row in the table containing the data. The table name is tblContent and the database is data1. I am very new to this so I apologize for my horrific coding. Thank you!

admin.php

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.1//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml11/DTD/xhtml11.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en">
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" type="text/css" media="screen" />

</head>

<body>

<div id="container"> <!-- Open container -->
    <div id="header">
        <h1><a href="index.html"><?php
                                    require_once 'classes.php';
                                    $rh = $database->getPageHeading();
                                    print($rh);
                                    ?></a></h1>
        <h2>                     <?php
                                    require_once 'classes.php';
                                    $rs = $database->getSubHeading();
                                    print($rs);
                                    ?></h2>
    </div>

    <div id="content">

<form method="post" action="" onSubmit="return verifyPageHeading()">

<table width="300" cellpadding="2" cellspacing="2">

    <tr>
        <td>Page Heading:</td>
        <td><input type="text" id="txtPageHeading" name="txtPageHeading" value="<?php
                                                            require_once 'classes.php';
                                                            $rh = $database->getPageHeading();
                                                            print($rh);
                                                            ?>" class="inputClass"></td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
        <td>Sub Heading:</td>
        <td><input type="text" id="txtSubHeading" name="txtSubHeading" value="<?php
                                                                require_once 'classes.php';
                                                                $rs = $database->getSubHeading();
                                                                print($rs);
                                                                ?>"  class="inputClass"></td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
        <td>Page Title:</td>
        <td><input type="text" id="txtPageTitle" name="txtPageTitle" value="<?php
                                                                require_once 'classes.php';
                                                                $rt = $database->getPageTitle();
                                                                print($rt);
                                                                ?>"  class="inputClass"></td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
        <td>MetaDescription:</td>
        <td><textarea style="width:300px;"cols="55" rows="5" name="txtMetaDescription"><?php
                                                                                         require_once 'classes.php';
                                                        $rd = $database->getMetaDescription();
                                                        print($rd);
                                                        ?></textarea></td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
        <td>MetaKeywords:</td>
        <td><input type="text" name="txtMetaKeywords" value="<?php
                                                require_once 'classes.php';
                                                $rk = $database->getMetaKeywords();
                                                print($rk);
                                                ?>"  class="inputClass"></td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
        <td>Content:</td>
        <td><textarea id="textarea1" name="txtContent" style="height: 170px; width: 300px;" rows="15" cols="10"> <?php                                  
                                                                require_once 'classes.php';
                                                                $rc = $database->getContent();
                                                                print($rc);
                                                                ?></textarea>
        <input type="submit" value="Save" style="background-color:;border:1px solid ;color:;width:200px;"></td>
    </tr>


        </table>
            </form>

</div>  

<div id="footer">

</div>

</div> <!-- Close id="container" -->
</body>

</html>
```

classes.php

```
<?php 

//Enter your database connection details here.
$host = 'localhost'; //HOST NAME.
$db_name = 'XXXXdata1'; //Database Name
$db_username = 'XXXXuser1'; //Database Username
$db_password = 'XXXXpass'; //Database Password

class database {
function __construct($pdo) {
    $this->pdo = $pdo;
}

function getPageHeading () {
    $query = $this->pdo->prepare('SELECT * FROM tblContent');
    $query->execute();
    return $query->fetchColumn(1);
}
function getSubHeading () {
    $query = $this->pdo->prepare('SELECT * FROM tblContent');
    $query->execute();
    return $query->fetchColumn(2);
}
function getContent () {
    $query = $this->pdo->prepare('SELECT * FROM tblContent');
    $query->execute();
    return $query->fetchColumn(3);
}
function getPageTitle () {
    $query = $this->pdo->prepare('SELECT * FROM tblContent');
    $query->execute();
    return $query->fetchColumn(4);
}
function getMetaDescription () {
    $query = $this->pdo->prepare('SELECT * FROM tblContent');
    $query->execute();
    return $query->fetchColumn(5);
}
function getMetaKeywords () {
    $query = $this->pdo->prepare('SELECT * FROM tblContent');
    $query->execute();
    return $query->fetchColumn(6);
}



}

try {
$pdo = new PDO('mysql:host='. $host .';dbname='.$db_name, $db_username, $db_password);
} catch (PDOException $e) {
exit('Error Connecting To DataBase');
}

$database = new Database($pdo);

?>
```

Comment: you want to edit your table values from web, is that your requirement?

Comment: Yes. I want to use my admin.php page to edit the table values.

Comment: can you share that table structure too?

Comment: http://imgur.com/5INzraH

Comment: Is that what you needed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out, see below. I used $_POST to get the current values from the admin.php page and UPDATE to replace the existing table info with the new information entered on the admin.php page. This updated the information which will then be reflected on my index.php page. I tested it and it is working correctly but I'm open if there is a better way to do this.

```
<?php

//Enter your database connection details here.
$host = 'localhost'; //HOST NAME.
$db_name = 'XXXXdb_name'; //Database Name
$db_username = 'XXXXuser'; //Database Username
$db_password = 'XXXXpass'; //Database Password


$PageHeading = $_POST['txtPageHeading'];
$SubHeading = $_POST['txtSubHeading'];
$PageTitle = $_POST['txtPageTitle'];
$MetaDescription = $_POST['txtMetaDescription'];
$MetaKeywords = $_POST['txtMetaKeywords'];
$Content = $_POST['txtContent'];

try {
$conn = new PDO('mysql:host='. $host .';dbname='.$db_name, $db_username, $db_password);
// set the PDO error mode to exception
$conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

$sql = "UPDATE tblContent SET PageHeading='$PageHeading', SubHeading='$SubHeading', 
PageTitle='$PageTitle', MetaDescription='$MetaDescription', MetaKeywords='$MetaKeywords', 
Content='$Content' WHERE PageID=1";

// Prepare statement
$stmt = $conn->prepare($sql);

// execute the query
$stmt->execute();

// echo a message to say the UPDATE succeeded
echo $stmt->rowCount() . " records UPDATED successfully";
}
catch(PDOException $e)
{
echo $sql . "<br>" . $e->getMessage();
}

$conn = null;

?>
```